# State not being sent to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have an application with a form that collects data from users. I want to store this data in MongoDB. However at the moment only the Id is being shown in the database.

I am sending the data in the following format:

```
let userData = [{
    Name: customerName,
    address: address,
    workType: work,
    time: date,
    imageOne: image1,
    imageTwo: image2,
    imageThree: image3,
  }];
 /* submitting the data */
  const scheduleEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post(
      "My url",
      userData
    )
    
      
  };
  /* end of submission*/
```

I have read a few questions here on Stack Overflow that the issue is the object in application and MongoDB are different. Here is my webhook code

```
exports = async function(payload, response) {

  if (payload.body) {
      const body =  EJSON.parse(payload.body.text());
      const customerEvents= context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("Curb").collection("Customer-event");
      
      const event = {
            Name: body.Name, 
   address: body.address,
    workType: body.workType,
    time: body.time,
    imageOne: body.image1,
    imageTwo: body.image2,
    imageThree: body.image3,
          
      };
  
      return await customerEvents.insertOne(event);
  }

  return  {}
```

I have done some tinkering with the names to see if anything will be sent, but so far nothing. I figured that if the issue were the names of the properties that at least one would go through, like the `Name` property.

My full page is viewable [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/Curb-Appeal/blob/main/src/pages/schedule.js).

Comment: As DariusP suggested you have Part1 assigning an array to object userData, but in Part2 you expect payload.body to be a single object and not an array.  I would be curious what payload.body.text() held before any attempts to parse as EJSON.

Comment: Editor's notes: (a) your posts need a lot of work to make them readable; (b) please observe correct case and spelling rules, use a spell checker; (c) line breaks are nearly never needed here - use paragraphs for readability; (d) don't beg, keep your writing succinct and technical; (e) it's OK to show permanent links of your work, but only if those links will be around in several years time. Mostly you can't guarantee that, so try to show everything you need to in your questions.

Comment: Please also consider changing your username. Readers don't need to see begging here, but moreover if you are determined to beg, it may reflect a sense of helplessness and needy behaviour that should be discouraged in software engineers. A sense of "can do" positivity will really aid you in your work.

Comment: Addendum: (f) inline code/IO samples can use single backticks - three is unnecessary. Use three just for block formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say only the Id is created on MongoDB, maybe there is a problem with the way the data is dealt with.

One possible cause is that `userData` is of type array. And you're never accessing it. Maybe try:

```
    axios.post(
      "My url",
      userData[0]
    )
```

Or just keep it as an object:

```
  let userData = {
    Name: customerName,
    address: address,
    workType: work,
    time: date,
    imageOne: image1,
    imageTwo: image2,
    imageThree: image3,
  };
```

Another suggestion is to try `payload.body.text` (instead of `.text()`). Or to check if it has other properties, like `.json` or `.data`.

Comment: It looks like that it was a type array,  so the `userData[0]` fixed it, I'm happy to have this solved thank you for your help.